# Требования к иконке для mono

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, vb.net, mono

Делаю winforms-приложение на vb.net. При попытке запустить его под mono (без wine, с установленным mono-vbnc) в Linux Mint 18 получаю ошибку

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: WinForms_SeeInnerException ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No valid icon entry were found.
  at System.Drawing.Icon.InitFromStreamWithSize (System.IO.Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height) <0x4046cc50 + 0x00f9b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) <0x4051fa00 + 0x001db> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Убрал иконку у приложения и формы, а также удалил иконку из ресурсов - ошибка исчезла.

Возможно ли запускать под mono приложение/форму с иконкой?
И какие на неё накладываются требования?

Можно ли сделать разные файлы ресурсов для разных конфигураций билда?

Компилирую в VS2015.

Comment: Вроде должно работать, исходя из этого бага: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30715

Comment: @VladD, что именно должно работать? У меня заработало только после удаления иконки из файла ресурсов. Пока она там была, программа не запускалась, даже несмотря на то, что иконка нигде не использовалась (я сначала убрал иконки приложения и формы, но в Form1.resx она осталась).

Comment: Иконки под Mono :) Тут [ещё один багрепорт](http://marc.info/?l=mono-bugs&m=118487985710397&w=2) вроде говорит, что не катит иконка 256x256, попробуете удалить только её?

Comment: @VladD, она была единственная и как раз-таки 256*256. И упс.. В винде её тоже не все открывают. Universal Viewer сказал "Out of system resources." o_O Хотя проводник показывает корректно.

Comment: Хм. А если поставить иконку поменьше и повторить эксперимент?

Comment: @VladD, заменил сначала на такую же (256*256), но после конвертирование в ico в XnView - объём увеличился в 10 раз (а все виндовые проги научились её открывать), но не помогло. Потом ужал её до 32*32 - так всё работает. Похоже, дело всё-таки в размере.

Comment: Судя по всему, это баг. Потому что по идее должно работать.

Comment: @VladD, не хочешь ответом написать?

Comment: Да, сейчас оформлю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Расследование в комментариях показало, что проблема с иконкой 256×256. Судя по всему, виноват [этот код](https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics/blob/master/System.Drawing/Icon.cs#L734), который умышленно игнорирует большой размер.

Таким образом, если есть единственная иконка размера 256×256, она не находится, и приложение [вылетает с исключением](https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics/blob/master/System.Drawing/Icon.cs#L764).

Имеет смысл добавить иконки меньшего размера, а эту иконку не удалять, таким образом то же приложение под другими системами сможет найти большую иконку.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Неожиданно нашёлся виноватый код, да.

Comment: Ага, неожиданно) Может, им написать куда-нибудь? Или они в курсе?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде, вот [этот баг](http://marc.info/?l=mono-bugs&m=118487985710397&w=2) как раз по теме. Но они говорят в коде об обратной совместимости, так что может быть имеет смысл открыть issue на гитхабе. Особенно если на свежей Windows 256×256 работает. Совместимость с багами старых версий Windows не нужна!